# How can I use a custom Code Climate configuration in GitLab CE?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ce, code-climate, code-climate-cli

I have trouble setting up the following environment. I’d like to quickly check the code quality of a few SASS files in my local GitLab repository. This is the contents of the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
include:
  - template: Code-Quality.gitlab-ci.yml

stages:
  - test
```

And I’ve put a `.codeclimate.yml` file in the root of the repository as well. That setup contains the SCSS lint plugin. But it does not pick up any custom configurations I’ve put in that file, when running a pipeline. It uses the default config and completely ignores the file.

What should I do to make sure the changes in `.codeclimate.yml` are picked up? I’m using the GitLab Community Edition by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Gitlab template(Code-Quality.gitlab-ci.yml) is using codeclimate for code scan.

We can create a `.codeclimate.yaml` file to specify the plugins (and other settings) during the scan.

Check the https://docs.codeclimate.com/docs/advanced-configuration to learn how to config the settings.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to solve this problem for hours now, turns out I had `.codeclimate.yml` specified inside my `.dockerignore` which meant it wasn't passed to the container that performs the analysis. Now it works.

So try checking that ;-)